# Ajax request only posts part of array with JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax

I have an array that gets updated within JavaScript.

Here's how I start the array...

```
columnArray = ["userID", "Date", "trialType", "cue", "target", "response", "accuracy", "lenAcc", "strictAcc", "fkpl", "totalTime"];
var dataArray = [];
dataArray.push(columnArray);
```

Then later I update the data based on what happens and some calculations I make...

```
dataArray.push(userID, new Date(), trialType, cue, target, response, accuracy, lenAcc, strictAcc, fkpl, totalTime);
```

When I show the array using this code...

```
document.getElementById("trial").innerHTML = dataArray;
```

...things look great (line breaks for formatting)

```
userID,Date,trialType,cue,target,response,accuracy,
lenAcc,strictAcc,fkpl,totalTime,
Ad31,Mon Dec 18 2017 11:35:55 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard 
Time),copy,hello,world,xzzvxzxvxzxcv,0,0,0,938,5001
```

However, when I use this function to save the data...

```
function saveData(){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "saveData.php",
    dataType: "application/json",
    ContentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: {"data": JSON.stringify(dataArray)},
  })
}
```

...I get only the header information (again line breaks for formatting)

```
[["userID","Date","trialType","cue","target","response","accuracy",
"lenAcc","strictAcc","fkpl","totalTime"]]
```

I read somewhere that perhaps my array needs to be an object and thus I should use...

```
var dataArray = {};
```

...instead of...

```
var dataArray = [];
```

But if I do that, can I still treat dataArray as a regular array (e.g., push contents to the end, store large amounts of data, etc.)?

Or is there some other issue going on?

Ideally, I'd like to have a single line for each "trial", so that the array is formatted on a line-by-line basis. But first I just want to get the data written correctly.

Thank you!

**SOLVED!**
The code works now. I was simply calling my Ajax save function BEFORE I was appending the data to the array with push(). Once I moved my save function to be called immediately after the data are pushed into the array, it saves the file with all pertinent information!

Comment: The flow of your code must be wrong somewhere. See https://jsfiddle.net/og481q9j/ - it outputs the whole array. However, I don't know what format your server is expecting to get this in, but a JS object containing key-value pairs would seem to make more logical sense and also be making use of the actual features of the language. Your way is a bit random. e.g. `var dataObj = { "userID": "Ad31", "Date": new Date(), "trialType": "copy"` ...etc. would be the conventional approach. If you need to add or amend properties after the initial declaration then it's simple - `dataObj.cue = "hello";`

Comment: So I fixed my problem, which I'll discuss above. And you were right -- it was the flow of the code. By moving my saveData function up above so that it occurs immediately after I push the data into the array, it works. Somehow, it was trying to save the data BEFORE I was pushing the new values into the array (*somehow* -- will investigate this more). Thank you!!!!

Comment: @KalifVaughn There's a "Post an answer" button at the bottom of the page. If you have an answer, you should post it as an answer and not as part of the question. That said, this is unlikely to be helpful to future visitors, so it might be better to just delete it.

Answer (score 0):

My problem has been solved. I simply was executing saveData() before I was filling the array with data.